# Какова сложность алгоритма у программы с рекурсивным вызовом?

Tags: python, алгоритм, сложность

Не могу понять как оценить сложность данной программы, т.к. в интернете нахожу только примеры с некоторыми циклами и их вложенностью. А какая же сложность алгоритма у программы с рекурсивным вызовом?

```
# The main function that recursively prints all repeated 
# permutations of the given string. It uses data[] to store 
# all permutations one by one 
def allLexicographicRecur (string, data, last, index): 
    length = len(string) 

    # One by one fix all characters at the given index and 
    # recur for the subsequent indexes 
    for i in xrange(length): 

        # Fix the ith character at index and if this is not 
        # the last index then recursively call for higher 
        # indexes 
        data[index] = string[i] 

        # If this is the last index then print the string 
        # stored in data[] 
        if index==last: 
            print toString(data) 
        else: 
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1) 

# This function sorts input string, allocate memory for data 
# (needed for allLexicographicRecur()) and calls 
# allLexicographicRecur() for printing all permutations 
def allLexicographic(string): 
    length = len(string) 

    # Create a temp array that will be used by 
    # allLexicographicRecur() 
    data = [""] * (length+1) 

    # Sort the input string so that we get all output strings in 
    # lexicographically sorted order 
    string = sorted(string) 

    # Now print all permutaions 
    allLexicographicRecur(string, data, length-1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Эта программа выводит все [размещения c повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) множества длины `n` по `n` элементов. Ее сложность O(n<sup>n</sup>)

Так будет попроще

```py
import itertools

def allLexicographic(string):
    for row in itertools.product(string, repeat=len(string)):
        print(''.join(row))
```

Что касается подсчета сложности, первый вызов рекурсивной функции пораждает еще `n` вызовов, и каждый из них еще по `n`, пока глубина будет меньше `n`.

Всего 1 + n + n<sup>2</sup> + ... n<sup>n-1</sup> = (n<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (n - 1) вызовов.

Каждый вызов делает по `n` изменений элементов массива, итого n(n<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (n - 1)

Кроме этого, на глубине `n`, будет суммарно сделано n<sup>n</sup> выводов на экран

Т.е. так или иначе получается количество операций пропорциональное n<sup>n</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Если я все правильно посчитал, то это N квадрат. Сложность простой рекурсии без циклов - N.

Подробнее можете прочитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/104219/).

*UPD*
 Упс, не увидел, что вызов рекурсии идет в цикле. Тогда @extrn прав, это будет N в степени N.

Прошу прощения)